# Value at Risk VaR with monthly return

Tags: normal-distribution, standardization, quantiles, finance

The picture below shows the problem. I have tried to solve in this way: 0,001*1,88+2400*0,002 by following a formula in theory slides. But obviously there is a problem in that. Could someone help me ? thank you

[image: problem]

Comment: Note that the [tag:var] tag refers to vector autoregression rather than value at risk.

Comment: Did you just randomly plugged numbers to a random formula?

Comment: No, the formula I had was: ∅^-1 * (1- α)* σ + μW0

Comment: Anyway, I think to be arrived at the solution by myself. If you want to know, the right formula should be this one (for 97% of confidence interval): W0* (1,88* σ - μ).